# Get SearchHitField type using ElasticSearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've started using the ElasticSearch (ES) Java API a few days ago.
Now I need given a query string obtain the results and manipulate them.

The problem is ES returns `SearchHitField` objects, which have a `value()` method.
But that method only returns `Object` objects.
How can I obtain the type os each field?

I supect the answer is in the ES indexes, but I didn't find it yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found a solution [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Java-API-to-get-a-mapping-td2988351.html).

Comment: Is there a better solution than that? I don't think requesting the index is a good idea each time I have a search request.